# Multi-step VLookup, Substitute, and then Evaluate Process

Tags: excel, vba

I have a three-step process that should end up giving me Boolean values of True/False and also an occasional #N/A or #VALUE (which I actually want to keep as errors). I am using a workbook with multiple named worksheets and am pulling cell values from one tab through a VLookup, replacing a string in those values, and then making those values into a formula to be evaluated. Here's what I have so far; I've included comments in the code explaining where I'm stuck.

```
Public Sub DetermineRowsToExamine()

'Define what our Rows are for the calculations
    Dim NumRecords As Long
    NumRecords = Workbooks("POVA Daily Reporter.xlsm").Worksheets("Paste Daily Data").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim CellsForFormula As Range
    Set CellsForFormula = Workbooks("POVA Daily Reporter.xlsm").Worksheets("Paste Daily Data").Range("g2", "G" & NumRecords)


'Now I Insert the VLookup
    Dim WSLogic As Worksheet
    Dim WSData As Worksheet
    Set WSData = Workbooks("POVA Daily Reporter.xlsm").Worksheets("Paste Daily Data")
    Set WSLogic = Workbooks("POVA Daily Reporter.xlsm").Worksheets("Logic Statements")

    CellsForFormula.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(WSData.Range("B2"), WSLogic.Range("A:D"), 4, False)

'This works in principle, but the problem is the "B2" in the VLookup - I need the "B2" to change to "B3" related
'to each row, just as it would if I pasted the rows down the columns as an cell formula

'Now I want to take that value and perform a replacement:
    CellsForFormula.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Range("g2"), "ZZZ", "C2")

'Again, this works great, but I need it to replace "G2" or "G3" or whatever cell it's in.

'Finally, I then want to evaluate that cell as if it were a formula. When the above calculations are working,
'I end up with:  AND(LEN(C2)=10,OR(LEFT(C2,2)="57",LEFT(C2,2)="13"))
'I want to evaluate this as a formula, basically making it =AND(LEN(C2)=10,OR(LEFT(C2,2)="57",LEFT(C2,2)="13"))


End Sub
```

I think what I'm just not understanding is how to get the Cell references in the VLookup and Substitute functions to relate to whatever row I'm in.

Comment: The might be a more esoteric way to do it, but I would simply do a For/Next loop through G2:Gx.

Comment: It looks to me like you are setting the cell values to the result of the Vlookup, but want the formulas in the cells?  If so you need to take out the Application.WorksheetFunction stuff, and do something like  = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],C[-7]:C[-4],4,FALSE)" , this particular example is if H2 is where the formula resided.  You would need to adjust based on where you have it.

Comment: Joe: Thanks for the suggestion. I thought about using a loop but was concerned it would take longer to run. The VLookup scans about 4500 rows in the other worksheet.

Comment: Alan: I'm not sure I understand your example. I am setting the value to the result of the VLookup because the result of the Vlookup isn't a formula - these results don't have the "=" in front of them or a true cell reference. Not sure if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Agreeing with what @AlanWaage is saying, you should put the actual `VLOOKUP` formula in the cell. Then, to get the formula to update relative to its location, you can utilize copy and paste. Finally, once you have the formulas there, you can copy and paste values, and do your replacement based on the values now in `CellsForFormula` range. See the updated code below:

```
' Put the formula in the first cell of your range
CellsForFormula(1, 1).Formula = _
    "=VLOOKUP(Paste Daily Data!B2,Logic Statements!$A$1:$D$10000,4,0)"

' Copy the formula to the rest of your range
CellsForFormula(1, 1).Copy _
    Destination:=Range(CellsForFormula(2, 1), CellsForFormula(NumRecords - 1, 1))

' Copy and paste values to just get the values in your range
CellsForFormula.Copy
CellsForFormula.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

' Execute your replacement
for each cell in CellsForFormula
    cell.Replace("ZZZ", cell.offset(0,-4).Address)
    'Use the line below instead of the line above if you only
    'want to replace if the entire value is "ZZZ"
    'cell.Replace("ZZZ", cell.offset(0,-4).Address,xlWhole)
    cell.Formula = "=" & cell.value
Next cell
```

**---EDIT---**

Note that I did `Logic Statements!$A$1:$D$10000` instead of `Logic Statements!A:D`; this will be much faster than having Excel examine all rows in the columns A:D. Make this number larger or smaller as you see fit, but you should try to avoid using complete column/row references in formulas unless necessary

Comment: Very helpful, Jaycal, thank you very much. I guess I was under the impression that using VBA's VLookup function is faster or somehow beneficial over pasting the formula into the cell. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, so I've made it a few steps further, but I'm still stuck on one part. When I use the `Call CellsForFormula.Replace("ZZZ", "C2")` function, I need the function to replace the "ZZZ" with "C#", with # being the row number of that cell. I tried `activecell.row`, but that doesn't work because only Cell G2 is actually active. How can I get the `Replace` function to replace the "ZZZ" with the correct row reference?

Comment: do you need ZZZ to be replaced with C2, C5, C7 etc... or the actual value in C2, C5, C7 etc..?

Comment: C2, C5, C7, etc. - It needs to be the cell reference, not the actual value.

Comment: Updated, notice the difference between the two lines of code that i indicated in the for loop

Comment: Wow! That worked!
Okay, now here's the next question. I need to make the result of all of those fabulous formulas you helped me create above into a formula itself. The values left after the above code read like this:
`AND(LEN($C$2)=10,OR(LEFT($C$2,2)="57",LEFT($C$2,2)="13"))`
Which is **awesome**; now I just need to take the cell's value and stick "=" in front of it.
So far I have something like this:
`CellsForFormula.Value = ("=" & CellsForFormula.Value)`
But this gives me a Run Time Error 13.

Comment: Now you've stumped me :) If I understand, this formula that you want will go into `CellsForFormula` (Column G), overwriting the values that exist; what was the purpose of populating the G column with the vlookup and the replace in the first place, especially if your AND formula is only looking at Column C, which isn't changing?

Comment: I definitely understand the confusion! Let me give a bit more of the story: Users input a pseudo-formula in the "Logic Statements" worksheet in this format: `AND(LEN(ZZZ)=10,ISNUMBER(VALUE(ZZZ)))`. They use that format because at the time they input it, they don't have a cell reference and at that time they don't put "=" in front of it because we need it to remain text and not calculate as a formula. The user input side unfortunately can't be changed. The VLookup pulls these pseudo-formulas based on column B in the "Paste Daily Data" worksheet. Once we have the correct formulas, then I need

Comment: to do the `Replace` function and then turn it into its final form. I hope that makes sense?

Comment: See updated (i think this is what you're looking for). You'll need to have a lot of confidence that your users are entering formulas in the right format :) It seems like all of this can be done with one formula though? Was that tried already?